# ASP.NET WebMethod Trims Leading 0 From String Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

I have a WebMethod as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public string CityState(string zip)
{
    if (zip.Length < 5) return string.Empty;
    //truncated for readability

     var data = "Foo";
     return data;
}
```

In an ascx control I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = { Zip: "09003"  };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/postalcodevalidator.asmx/CityState",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Woohoo");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Boohoo.")
            }
        });
</script>
```

During the request the leading 0 gets trimmed from the string.  How can I prevent that?

Comment: Somebody, somewhere, thinks it's an integer. I presume that's not somewhere in the land of "truncated for readability"? Can you get a look (with fiddler maybe) at the JSON that `data` (in the javascript) is being serialized to? If there are no quotes around `09003` in there, that's the culprit.

Comment: Presumed correctly. I've never really used fiddler.  Now is the time I suppose.

Comment: It arrives *at* the webmethod mangled from the client? Fiddler's wicked cool, you're gonna love it.

Comment: @plntxt You could also hit F12 in your browser and look at the network tab to see what the request looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "worked", meaning, this stopped whatever converted my string to int back to string but I don't know why or where that conversion happened.

In any event my "solution" is to wrap my string in a string so to speak.

```
var data = { Zip: '"09003"'  };
```

Note the single ticks around the double ticks. By doing this I guess I tricked whatever was trying to do the conversion.

Comment: did you try without any quotes? numbers don't usually have quotes in an object. i don't know what happens to them in $.ajax calls though. (...mmm, unless you actually want a string, then nvmnd.)